# C - fork and printf behavior

Tags: c, linux, fork

Testing the fork function in combination with printf i found some strange behavior

For example, the code:

```
int main(){
     if(fork()==0){
          printf("TestString");
     }
}
```

doesn't print out anything, while

```
int main(){
  if(fork()==0) {
     printf("TestString\n");
  }
}
```

prints out TestString correctly. Why does printing a new line change the behavior? I suspect it might do something with fflush(), but i am not sure. Could i get and explanation or a link where i can read up on it? Thank you for the answer in advance.

EDITED: The explanation i am looking for is what is actually flushing and why is \n same as flushing.

Comment: Yes you need to use `fflush(stdout)` or use newline just what you did.

Comment: printf is buffered, and the content of the buffer is displayed when a newline '\n' character is encountered. Flushing means to clear the content of the buffer associated with printf.
I tested this code and it prints "TestString" in both the cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Linux (at least), `stdout` is *line buffered*. This means that anything you write to it will not actually appear on the screen until a `'\n'` is encountered. If you don't like this behaviour you can change the buffering policy with `setbuf()`, but you will have to do it as soon as your program starts (well, actually before any writes to the stream), or call `fflush()` whenever you want to flush the buffer contents, as you said.

Remember that buffers are also flushed anyway when a program ends and its opened streams are automatically closed.